# What are the dimensions of US outlet holes?

Tags: charger, adapter, plug, socket, outlet

I am specifically referring to the standard NEMA 5-15 three hole outlet that is used in North America. What are the dimensions of the holes in the outlets?

Surprisingly, I am having difficulty in finding this information on line.

Comment: cross-posting is frowned upon on SE sites. http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/87280/what-are-the-dimensions-of-us-outlet-holes

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I needed it because I'm cutting out some dongles with an integrated wire wrap I can stick wall warts into for storage. Anybody designing a product w/ custom US plugs would need this information for CAD (like the integrated wall wart/cord wrap/IoT dongle I designed last year). There are lots of reasons someone might want to know this.

Answer (score 3):

Not to be a smartass, but [Wikipedia's got you covered.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEMA_connector)

The Nema 5-15 is an updated version of the NEMA 1-15.  The blades are the same.
From Wikipedia (NEMA-1):

> All NEMA 1 devices are two-wire non-grounding devices (hot-neutral) rated for 125 V maximum. NEMA 1-15P plugs have two parallel flat blades, 1⁄4 inch (6.35 mm) wide, 0.06 inches (1.524 mm) thick, 5⁄8–23⁄32 inch (15.875–18.256 mm) long, and spaced 1⁄2 inch (12.7 mm) apart.

From Wikipedia (NEMA-5):

> All NEMA 5 devices are three-wire grounding devices (hot-neutral-ground) rated for 125 V maximum, with the 5-15, 5-20 and 5-30 being grounded versions of the 1-15, 1-20 and 1-30, respectively. The addition is a 3⁄16-inch (4.763 mm) diameter round or U-shaped ground pin, 1⁄8 in (3.175 mm) longer than the power blades (so the device is grounded before the power is connected) and located below them by 1⁄4 in (6.35 mm) edge-to-edge or 15⁄32 in (11.91 mm) center-to-center.

Answer (score 2):

I checked the NEMA website and I found the drawing you are looking for on page 10 of this document:
[NEMA WD 6 - Non-Locking Plugs and Receptacles - Excerpt](https://www.nema.org/Standards/ComplimentaryDocuments/NEMA%20WD%206%20-%20Non-Locking%20Plugs%20and%20Receptacles%20-%20Excerpt.pdf)